# AngularJS add's automatic space before and after variable

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to understand why im get blank space before and after my variable when i send from index.html to controller.

In my index.html :

```
    <input class="form-control" id='photo' type="texte"
           placeholder="photo" name="photo" ng-model="modifphoto">
    <input class="form-control" id='nom' type="texte"
           placeholder="nom" name="nom" ng-model="modifnom">
    <input class="form-control" id='prenom' type="texte"
           placeholder="prenom" name="prenom" ng-model="modifprenom">
    <input class="boutonModif" id="connect" type="submit"
           value="connexion">
```

If i write "test" and send,when i do a console.log of "modifprenom" in my controller.js i got " test ".

And the same things appens here :

```
<label ng-repeat="level in niveau">
  <input type="radio" name="selectedLevel[]" value="{{level}}"
         ng-checked="selection.indexOf(level)>-1"
         ng-click="choixNiveau(level)">{{level}}
</label>
```

My $scope.niveau :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F745b.png)

[image]

When i do a console.log (without space between ':' and variable)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Ph3.png)

[image]

You see space here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/598fD.png)

[image]

And obviously on my service.js and server.js, this function is used for changing name in my "game" so my new name will be " Dylan " and not "Dylan".
So when i'm trying to do request in mongodb from server, im doing a request with a wrong name because of space.

I have tried everything ...
- use .trim() 
- use .replace ...
- changing browser

So i don't know how to deal with it, i'm really need help.

Comment: Can you please share a live example showing the issue via plnkr or codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space betweeon `:` and variable - that's what console.log does.

If you don't want the space, use `+` operator to stitch strings together.

```
 $scope.test = "test";
    $scope.click = function() {
    console.log("Test :" + $scope.test);
}
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/5MjDSOGRiF3v0ONyURXB?p=preview